# Mysql too many connections but not visible in fullprocess list

Tags: mysql, connection

I got a big problem, I guess it's something like a dos attack but I am not sure.

Since this morning, my database is very slow and gives me 7/10 times a too many connections error or tries to login with www-data user (as following up of the too many connections error?).

I tried to locate the issue by mysql command line with 'show fullprocess list' but it gives me just one response back and that 'me'.

What can I do about this? The websites are still running ok, but mysql is overused I guess.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

...If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise, you can see only your own threads...

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you just need to increase the max_connections in my.cnf(usually located at /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf) then restart your mysql server, you could try the next value for a start:

```
max_connections=1000
```

Comment: What is a normal connection limit for mysql? it's for 100 now. I optimized some queries which did already a great job

Comment: The default is 100 but it might need to be increased on some of the servers, this is a normal practice.